# Python/Pandas: Compare multiple columns in two dataframes and remove row if no matches found

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am learning Python with Pandas and trying to work out the most efficient way to compare multiple selected columns on 2 dataframes to find a match. For example, if I have the following two dataframes:

```
Frame 1
      A     B    C    D    E    F    
001   10    0    0    10   0    10


Frame 2
      A     B    C    D    E    F
200   10    0    10   0    10   0
201   0     10   10   0    0    10
202   0     10   0    0    0    0
203   0     0    0    10   0    10
```

I'm looking for a way to compare columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` in the 2 dataframes in order to drop rows which do not match `10` in any column.

In this case, I would expect it to drop rows `201` and `202` because there are no matches, where row `200` and `203` had 1 match (even though row `200` has 1 column that does not match).

I've tried looping through all the rows in Frame 2, compare

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for ix, row in frame_2():
    for letter in letters:
        if frame_1[letter].values[0] != frame_2.loc[ix, letter]:
            frame_2.drop(ix, inplace=True)
            break
```

This removed some rows but not all.

Is there an efficient way to loop through all the rows and check if there's a single match in any of the columns of another dataframe?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by match? That the rows in Frame 2 match the rows in Frame 1? If so, is a 0 and a 0 not a match?

Comment: Ah sorry. I should have been clearer. Matching only if column values are both 10, so 0 and 0 would not be a match.

Comment: Updated my question, hopefully, it's a little clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think simpliest solution is replace non `10` to one value in `df1` and another value in `df2`, compare each column with `isin` for possible compare more values if `df1` has more rows, create `boolean` DataFrame, `concat` and filter by `any` for test at least one `True` per row:

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

out = []
for letter in letters:
    m = df2[letter].mask(lambda x: x!=10, 0).isin(df1[letter].mask(lambda x: x!=10, 1))
    out.append(m)

df = df2[pd.concat(out, axis=1).any(axis=1)]
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = df2[np.logical_or.reduce(out)]
```